# My newly developed website showing [ Not secure | www.tara5.com ] in chrome ,why??? how to fix?

Tags: google-chrome, security, url, web

I have just end up developing a website for my client, But when i open it in chrome then its showing not secure in the left of site address, I have just started my freelance career not have much experience please tell me how to fix this issue and most importantly why this is happening ?

Comment: Please give details about server and site setup.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

In January 2017, with the release of Chrome 56, a **Not secure** message will be presented on pages with password and credit card form fields that are not protected with an **SSL/TLS certificate**.

[image]

When a page is loaded in Chrome 56, Google will look for forms that collect passwords and credit card numbers, plus check for valid SSL certificates that provide secure HTTPS connections.

---

### To Resolve Warnings

To ensure that the Not Secure warning is not displayed for your pages, you must ensure that all forms containing `<input type=password>` elements and any inputs detected as credit card fields are present only on secure origins. This means that the top-level page must be HTTPS and, if the input is in an iframe, that iframe must also be served over HTTPS.

further details can be found on [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn)

**Tip** : You can find your unsecure forms from this free tool by godady. [sslchecker.godaddy.com](https://sslchecker.godaddy.com/?isc=cardigan)

Answer (score 0):

This message is generally displayed by browsers when sites use the http protocol instead of the https protocol.   https is an encrypted protocol, thus anyone listening to data sent and received cannot see what has been sent (which is important for login credentials, emails, credit card numbers etc.

[more on http/https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSL installed then you have to force https for your website via htaccess file, you shall search for "how to force ssl in htaccess", and if you have already one but your website appears as not secure, you might have a mixed content in your pages. Try to locate any links start with http and change it to https instead. If you did not install SSL for your website then you may get a free one for 90 days and after that buy another one.

Answer (score 0):

Google-chrome shows 'Not Secure warning' for pages served over HTTP, regardless of whether or not the page contains sensitive input fields. Put SSL/ TLS on your website and it'll be served over HTTPS.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn